# How to delete a reroute node?

Tags: node-editor

How do I delete a reroute node in the node editor without deleting the connection(s)? Or is this not possible?

Comment: Ctrl+x deletes any active node and keeps the link preserved if node wrangler is installed.

Comment: I thought this worked regardless of whether Node Wrangler is installed - isn‘t this standard functionality?

Comment: @RichSedman, to be honest I've used node wrangler for so long now I just assumed this function was one of the many added tools that came along with it, but it appears that you are correct. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First: make sure you have the [Node Wrangler add-on](http://gregzaal.github.io/node-wrangler/) installed and enabled.

Then, use `ctrl` + `X` to delete the reroute without removing the connections.